# How can I check if form input is numeric in PHP?

Tags: php, validation, numeric

I need to be able to see if a form input in PHP is numeric.  If it is not numeric, the website should redirect.  I have tried is_numeric() but it does not seem to work.

Code examples will be nice.

I am developing a shopping cart that accepts an integer value for the quantity. I am trying this:

```
if(!is_numeric($quantity)){
                //redirect($data['referurl']."/badinput");
                echo "is not numeric";
        }
```

Comment: please poste some code so we can understand why is_numeric() is not working for you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
if(!is_numeric($quantity == 0)){
                //redirect($data['referurl']."/badinput");
                echo "is not numeric";
```

What you have here are two nested conditions.
Let's say $quantity is 1.

The first condition evaluates 1 == 0 and returns FALSE.
The second condition checks if FALSE is numeric and returns FALSE because FALSE is not numeric.

just write:

```
if (!is_numeric($quantity))
{
    echo 'is not numeric';
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You should probably explain what you mean by "numeric" - integral, floating point, exponential notation etc? [`is_numeric()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) will accept all of these.

If you want to check that a string contains nothing other than digits, then you could use a regular expression, e.g.

```
/^\d+$/
```

If you're going to use the actual value as if it were an integer, you'll probably want to pass it through [`intval()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) anyway, which will return `0` if the value cannot be parsed - if `0` is a valid value, then you'll probably have to handle that in some way, maybe by constraining the lower range of the value.

Comment: There's a small error in your regex.  Should be /^\d+$/
You need to escape the d.

Answer (score 2):

It might also be wise to do some client side validation of the input using JavaScript.

The round-trip to the server and back is a long one for what might amount to a typo, and you'll reduce server overhead by making the client browser do a bit of the quality assurance beforehand.

Comment: Very late comment here, but please if you do the above, do this as well as server side validation for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Check [is_int](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) and [is_numeric](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php).  There are examples in each of the links.  If you need more help, I would post the data you are having problems with and a code sample.

EDIT:

```
$quantity == 0
```

will always be numeric, since it will return a boolean value (1 or 0).  The correct thing to do it:

```
if ( is_numeric( $quantity ) ) {
...
}
```

or

```
if ( is_int( $quantity ) ) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is [`ctype_digit`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php). From the docs:

```
Checks if all of the characters in the provided string, text, are numerical. Returns TRUE if every character in the string text is a decimal digit, FALSE otherwise.

<?php
$strings = array('1820.20', '10002', 'wsl!12');
foreach ($strings as $testcase) {
    if (ctype_digit($testcase)) {
        echo "The string $testcase consists of all digits.\n";
    } else {
        echo "The string $testcase does not consist of all digits.\n";
    }
}
?>
```

> The above example will output:
> The string 1820.20 does not consist
> of all digits.
> The string 10002 consists of all digits.
> The
> string wsl!12 does not consist of all digits.

```
<?php

$numeric_string = '42';
$integer        = 42;

ctype_digit($numeric_string);  // true
ctype_digit($integer);         // false (ASCII 42 is the * character)

is_numeric($numeric_string);   // true
is_numeric($integer);          // true
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What Rob said, although instead of regular expressions to check for digits, I would use [ctype_digit](http://php.net/ctype_digit)

Answer (score 0):

tharkun has the best answer so far.  If you're asking a question like this, it's my guess that you don't really want to start messing around with reg-exp's just yet.

Re-think your logic.  Why do you want to check to see if $quantity==0 is a numeric result?  If you're trying to avoid errors b/c you think it's possible for quantity to not have an assigned value, you're checking a little late.  This is a very common (and nefarious) security hole in your application -- if $quantity has a value derived at all from user input, please make sure to sanitize the input before it reaches this point in execution.  As a smaller part of the issue, you will not need to assign a default value, because you sanitized your input previously (and that sanitization is where you'd deal with a 'no input' situation).

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, the entire problem was from a typo.  
Silly me

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions: `/^\d+$/` should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$numeric = "1"; //true default

$string = trim($_GET['string']);

$chkarray = array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", ",", ".");

for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) { 
    if (!in_array(substr($string, $i, 1), $chkarray)) {
        $numeric = "0";
        break;
    }
}
```